# CSS Cell Margin

Tags: html, css, cell, margin, css-tables

In my HTML document, I have a table with two columns and multiple rows. How can I increase the space in between the first and second column with css? I've tried applying "margin-right: 10px;" to each of the cells on the left hand side, but to no effect.

Comment: There is a good CSS solution here, newly updated: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21551008/2827823

Answer (score 114, accepted):

Apply this to your first `<td>`:

```
padding-right:10px;
```

***HTML example:***

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td style="padding-right:10px">data</td>
      <td>more data</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: A far better approach to it would be to use border-collapse : seperate

Comment: Just in case someone was copy/pasting the border-collapse technique the above comment, it should be `border-collapse: separate` (there was a typo in the spelling of `separate` above)

Comment: Also, if you want to define the amount of space between the borders, you will have to use `border-spacing: 5px;`

Comment: `border-spacing` also adds space between rows.  Unfortunately, there is not a separate property for vertical and horizontal spacing.

Comment: `border-spacing` takes two arguments - one for horizontal and one for vertical.

Answer (score 166):

A word of warning: though `padding-right` might solve your particular (visual) problem, it is not the right way to add spacing **between** table cells. What `padding-right` does for a cell is similar to what it does for most other elements: it adds space **within** the cell. If the cells do not have a border or background colour or something else that gives the game away, this can mimic the effect of setting the space between the cells, but not otherwise.

As someone noted, margin specifications are ignored for table cells:

[CSS 2.1 Specification – Tables – Visual layout of table contents](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#table-layout)

> Internal table elements generate
> rectangular boxes with content and
> borders. Cells have padding as well.
> Internal table elements do not have
> margins.

What's the "right" way then? If you are looking to replace the `cellspacing` attribute of the table, then `border-spacing` (with `border-collapse` disabled) is a replacement. However, if per-cell "margins" are required, I am not sure how that can be correctly achieved using CSS. The only hack I can think of is to use `padding` as above, avoid any styling of the cells (background colours, borders, etc.) and instead use container DIVs inside the cells to implement such styling.

I am not a CSS expert, so I could well be wrong in the above (which would be great to know! I too would like a table cell margin CSS solution).

Comment: This is great and all for padding, but what about for margin? I want to add space outside of the cell that contains a border. Margin CSS seems to have no affect on cells.

Comment: Levitikon, that's right - margins do not work for reasons above. The only way to get what you want, AFAIK, is to wrap the contents of the cell in a DIV, add the margin *and* border to that DIV, rather than the cell.

Comment: I posted a CSS solution a long time ago (updated it today): http://stackoverflow.com/a/21551008/2827823

Answer (score 35):

If you can't use padding (for example you have borders in td) try this

```
table { 
           border-collapse: separate;
           border-spacing: 2px;
}
```

Comment: You can check more about border-collapse : separate here http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/border-collapse/

Answer (score 15):

I realize this is quite belated, but for the record, you can also use CSS selectors to do this (eliminating the need for inline styles.) This CSS applies padding to the first column of every row:

```
table > tr > td:first-child { padding-right:10px }
```

And this would be your HTML, sans CSS!:

```
<table><tr><td>data</td><td>more data</td></tr></table>
```

This allows for much more elegant markup, especially in cases where you need to do lots of specific formatting with CSS.

Answer (score 15):

margin does not work unfortunately on individual cells, however you could add extra columns between the two cells you want to put a space between...  another option is to use a border with the same colour as the background...

Comment: It seems like border has the same problem as padding - it adds space between the cell content and boundary, not outside the boundary.

Answer (score 13):

You can simply do that:

```
<html>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>one</td>
        <td width="10px"></td>
        <td>two</td>
    </tr>
</table>
</html>
```

No CSS is required :) This 10px is your space.

Comment: this is good, simple, and effective, thanks for reminding me +1

Comment: This is not a good approach for separation of structure and styling. It's not a case of whether or not CSS is required - CSS should be used for something like this.

Comment: shouldn't be <td style="width:10px;"></td>

Comment: Remember, the simplest solutions are the best. Method with inline style is also good :)

Comment: It working for my specific case. Very creative. Thank you

Answer (score 10):

Try `padding-right`. You're not allowed to put `margin`'s between cells.

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td style="padding-right: 10px;">one</td>
      <td>two</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 4):

This solution work for `td`'s that need both `border` and `padding` for styling.
 (Tested on Chrome 32, IE 11, Firefox 25)

```
CSS:
table {border-collapse: separate; border-spacing:0; }   /*  separate needed      */
td { display: inline-block; width: 33% }  /*  Firefox need inline-block + width  */
td { position: relative }                 /*  needed to make td move             */
td { left: 10px; }                        /*  push all 10px                      */
td:first-child { left: 0px; }             /*  move back first 10px               */
td:nth-child(3) { left: 20px; }           /*  push 3:rd another extra 10px       */

/*  to support older browsers we need a class on the td's we want to push
    td.col1 { left: 0px; }
    td.col2 { left: 10px; }
    td.col3 { left: 20px; }
*/

HTML:
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class='col1'>Player</td>
        <td class='col2'>Result</td>
        <td class='col3'>Average</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

---

**Updated 2016**

Firefox now support it without `inline-block` and a set `width`

```css
table {border-collapse: separate; border-spacing:0; }
td { position: relative; padding: 5px; }
td { left: 10px; }
td:first-child { left: 0px; }
td:nth-child(3) { left: 20px; }
td { border: 1px solid gray; }


/* CSS table */
.table {display: table; }
.tr { display: table-row; }
.td { display: table-cell; }

.table { border-collapse: separate; border-spacing:0; }
.td { position: relative; padding: 5px; }
.td { left: 10px; }
.td:first-child { left: 0px; }
.td:nth-child(3) { left: 20px; }
.td { border: 1px solid gray; }
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Player</td>
    <td>Result</td>
    <td>Average</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<div class="table">
  <div class="tr">
    <div class="td">Player</div>
    <div class="td">Result</div>
    <div class="td">Average</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This also worked for css tables (display:table*) made out of divs.

Answer (score 4):

Using **border-collapse: separate;** didn't work for me, because I only need a margin in-between the table cells not on the sides of the table.

I came up with the next solution:

-**CSS**

```
.tableDiv{
    display: table;
}

.cellSeperator {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 20px;
}

.cell1 {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 200px;
}

.cell2 {
    display: table-cell;
    width: 50px;
}
```

-**HTML**

```
<div class="tableDiv">
    <div class="cell1"></div>
    <div class="cellSeperator"></div>
    <div class="cell2"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't single out individual columns in a cell in that manner.  In my opinion, your best option is to add a `style='padding-left:10px'` on the second column and apply the styles on an internal div or element.  This way you can achieve the illusion of a greater space.

Answer (score 2):

If you have control of the width of the table, insert a padding-left on all table cells and insert a negative margin-left on the whole table.

```
table {
    margin-left: -20px;
    width: 720px;
}

table td {
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Note, the width of the table needs to include the padding/margin width. Using the above as an example, the visual width of the table will be 700px.

This is not the best solution if you're using borders on your table cells.

Answer (score 2):

### SOLUTION

I found the best way to solving this problem was a combination of trial and error and reading what was written before me:

http://jsfiddle.net/MG4hD/

As you can see I have some pretty tricky stuff going on... but the main kicker of getting this to looking good are:

PARENT ELEMENT (UL): border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: .25em; margin-left: -.25em; 
CHILD ELEMENTS (LI): display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle;

**HTML**

```
<ul>
<li><span class="large">3</span>yr</li>
<li>in<br>stall</li>
<li><span class="large">9</span>x<span class="large">5</span></li>
<li>on<br>site</li>
<li>globe</li>
<li>back<br>to hp</li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul { border: none !important; border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: .25em; margin: 0 0 0 -.25em; }
li { background: #767676 !important; display: table-cell; vertical-align: middle; position: relative; border-radius: 5px 0; text-align: center; color: white; padding: 0 !important; font-size: .65em; width: 4em; height: 3em; padding: .25em !important; line-height: .9; text-transform: uppercase; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Following Cian's solution of setting a border in place of a margin, I discovered you can set border color to transparent to avoid having to color match the background. Works in FF17, IE9, Chrome v23. Seems like a decent solution provided you don't also need an actual border.

Answer (score 1):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table{
border-spacing: 16px 4px;
}

 td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>  
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>  
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>  
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Using padding is not correct way of doing it, it may change the look but it is not what you wanted. This may solve your issue.

Comment: This solution is already posted, no need for 2 answers saying the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use both of them:

```
padding-right:10px;

padding-right:10%;
```

But it's better to use with **%**.

Comment: I upvoted, but you might have explained **why** it is better to use `%`

Comment: Normally % is used to make responsive.

Comment: Plus one - maybe you could edit your answer to say so? Not veryone who reads might read the comments.. If you want to add a link to something about responsive design, even better :-)

Answer (score 1):

If padding isn't working for you, another work around is to add extra columns and set a margin via width using `<colgroup>`. None of the padding solutions above were working for me as I was trying to give the cell border itself a margin, and this is what solved the problem in the end:

```
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col>
    <col width="20px">
    <col>
  </colgroup>
  <tr>
     <td>data</td>
     <td></td>
     <td>more data</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

Style the borders of the table cells using :nth-child so that the 2nd and third columns appear to be a single column.

```
table tr td:nth-child(2) { border: 1px solid black; border-right:0; }
table tr td:nth-child(3) { border: 1px solid black; border-left:0; }
```

Comment: That is masking the problem, not answering it. No one will learn how to do it properly by doing that