# left/margin-left value for a table-cell div

Tags: css, margin, css-tables, leftalign

I have this html:

```
<div id="main">
   //contents
</div>
```

and this css:

```
#main {
   padding:10px;
   margin-top:5px;
   display:table-cell;
   font-family:Calibri;
   font-size:25px;
   background-color:#50aafb;
}
```

and i have javascript that calculates how much to move the `main` div to left/margin-left. The div isn't moving because of the `display:table-cell` but i need that for something else...

**How do i resolve this?**

**UPDATE: http://jsfiddle.net/yueCM/**

**UPDATE 2:**
Javascript:

```
$(window).load(function() {
   var l = ( $(document).width() - $('#main').width() ) / 2;
   $('#main').animate({marginLeft:l}, 200); 
});
```

**SOLUTION (for me):**
changed `table-cell` to `table`.

**SOLUTION (found by @Sparky672):**
https://stackoverflow.com/a/2986792/594235

Wrap the `table-cell` div in another div (with `block` display for example) and apply the JS to that div.

Comment: [Show us some javascript, bra.](http://www.jsfiddle.net)

Comment: 1 sec because is php generated... i need to arrange it a little

Comment: Demo is great, but please also include the JS within the question.  Links go dead and these questions must live on.

Comment: so @Sparky672 can you help me with a solution?

Comment: So Sp3ct3R, can you post your JS within the question please?

Comment: Thank-you.  AFAIK, you cannot use `margin` with `table-cell`.  See:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/2986792/594235

Comment: I found a solution for me, changed `table-cell` to `table`, but maybe someone else can't do that. If anyone can find a solution(without changing table-cell) post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `inline-block` instead of `table-cell` : [**demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/gionaf/Rb3gp/)

`#main` is just the wrapper, it won't hurt. Browser support is similar: [`inline-block`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=inline-block) , [`table-cell`](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table).

For IE<8 support, add:

```
*zoom: 1;
*display: inline;
```