# why the margin padding doesn't work in table td and tr?

Tags: html, css

```
<table  border="0" style="padding:10px;width: 960px;border-collapse: collapse;">

   <tbody>
<tr>
<td  style="padding: 0"><img src="8.jpg" alt="" /></td>
<td  style="padding: 0"><img src="98.jpg" alt="" /></td>
<td  style="padding: 0"><img src="998.jpg" alt="" /></td>
<td  style="padding: 0"><img src="1998.jpg" alt="" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td  style="background-color: #757575;">11194</td>
<td  style="background-color: #757575;">11194</td>
<td  style="background-color: #757575;">11194</td>
<td  style="background-color: #757575;">11194</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td  style="padding: 0"><img src="8.jpg" alt="" /></td>
<td  style="padding: 0"><img src="98.jpg" alt="" /></td>
<td  style="padding: 0"><img src="998.jpg" alt="" /></td>
<td  style="padding: 0"><img src="1998.jpg" alt="" /></td>
</tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

why i can't add margin padding to the tr and td? i want the td  (`<td  style="background-color: #757575;">11194</td>`) have margin-right.namely, each separated by some space. but can't work. how to correct it. and the second tr have some space between the following tr.

Comment: See my answer and provide the extra css if you have used rather than inline style on table. So i can see if some thing is missing in the question.

Answer (score 8):

margin specifications are ignored for table cells
Refer: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html
and [CSS Cell Margin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716442/css-cell-margin)

> Internal table elements generate rectangular boxes with content and
>   borders. Cells have padding as well. Internal table elements do not
>   have margins.

If you wanna add padding, just set border-collapse:separate
refer: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/playit.asp?filename=playcss_border-collapse

Comment: but if in a table, i want to there is no white space between the first tr and the second tr. but the second tr with the third tr have. thank you. i add border-spacing:0 to the tr,but not work

Comment: add height:100% to img element.

Comment: Have you tried yet? If it's not what you want, plz let me know.

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are asking for `border-collapse;` so try using it...

```
table {
   border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

If you want to add `padding` you can do it like

```
table.class_name td {
   padding: 0; 
}
```

Comment: could you have a try?althouth i set td (<td style="background-color: #757575;margin-right:10px;">11194</td>). those are all connect with each. both are not have space.

Comment: @user1932607 sorry but am not getting you

Comment: <td style="background-color: #757575;margin-right:10px;">11194</td><td style="background-color: #757575;margin-right:10px;">11194</td> i want to make there are some white space between them

Comment: @user1932607 check this out do you want something like this? http://jsfiddle.net/vryqU/

Comment: yes,if not using a white border, using margin or padding, can get that

Comment: @user1932607 that I used just for showing you that was that the thing you wanted, so here you go this is the correct way http://jsfiddle.net/vryqU/1/

Comment: one more question,i want to there is no white space between the first tr and the second tr. but the second tr with the third tr have. thank you. i add border-spacing:0 to the tr,but not work

Answer (score 2):

The reason because you are giving padding on `table` element and on `td` and you are giving `padding:0`

Remove `border-collapse: collapse` from `table` element and you can handle padding and margin easily in this table.

See the demo fiddle for concepts: http://jsfiddle.net/GVt3z/

Note: Above fiddle is not containing exact answer.

See updated fiddle for margin-right space but with different technique.

http://jsfiddle.net/GVt3z/1/

Comment: could you have a try?althouth i set td (<td style="background-color: #757575;margin-right:10px;">11194</td>). those are all connect with each. both are not have space.

Comment: You can not give margin on td elements you can give padding to them, because they are all the childs of tr and tr is child element of table element.

Comment: you can give margin on table elements and give padding to td elements.

Comment: see my updated answer and see this fiddle after my answer http://jsfiddle.net/GVt3z/2/ .

Answer (score 0):

add "display:inline-block" to all elemans of table.

```
td{
  display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).