# Why doesn't margin hold for td?

Tags: css

I have spent the last several hours trying to *understand* why the margin CSS property (at least) for `td` elements is basically ignored.

For example, this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kynn/L9F4r/) shows a "simulation" of a table row using `div` elements, followed by a "real" `table` element with a single `tr`.  (I give the full code for all this at the end of this post.)  The `div` that simulates a `tr` has been given class `TR`, and, similarly, the `div`s that simulate `td`s have been given class `TD`.  The CSS for `div.TR` has been kept as close as possible to that for `tr` (the only exceptions are those CSS directives that do not apply to `tr` in this case).  Similarly, the CSS for `div.TD` and `td` should be almost identical.  In particular:

```
div.TD,td{border:1px solid black;}
div.TD,td{margin:15px;padding:5px}
```

Furthermore, each `div.TD` and each `td` contains an empty `div` element, with the following dimensions:

```
div.TD > div,td > div{width:90px;height:60px;}
```

As you can see, the CSS specs for both `div.TD` and `td` elements have the same margin, border, and padding specs, and have contents of identical dimensions.  Yet, as shown in the image below, only the `div.TD` elements show the specified margin and border.  For the `td`, both of these dimensions are effectively 0.    (Also, similarly puzzling is the fact that the border specified for the `div.TR` element is visible, but not the identically-specified one for the `tr` element.)

[image: result]

The top row is the "simulation" using divs, the bottom row comes from a bona fide `table` element row.  The light-brown region visible in the top row corresponds to the specified 15px margin.  The green region (visible in both the "simulated" and "real" table cells) corresponds to the specified 5px padding.

> I want to *understand* why this inconsistency of behavior

...but I have not been able to find any explanation.  In other words, *what is the rationale/motivation for this inconsistency.*  Or at least, how could I have quickly found out the official CSS rules responsible for this apparent inconsistency.  (I did search for this, but I did not find it.  More specifically, what I did find *implied*—by omission—that there should be no difference between the two cases shown above.)

(Everything I have found have been, at best, recipes for how to achieve a particular effect, but these recipes shed no light on the question of the inconsistency of behavior.  Such solutions are basically superficial band-aids, because they don't fix the underlying lack of understanding that leads to the question in the first place.)

---

OK, here's the code alluded to above, as promised:

**CSS**

```
/* basic reset */
body{background:white;}
html,body,div,table,tbody,tfoot,thead,tr,th,td{margin:0;padding:0;border:0;outline:0}
table{border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
/* demo-specific css begins here */
div.TR{display:table;}
div.TR,tr{border:1px solid #EE0000;}
div.TR,tr{background:#E8B36D;}
div.TD{float:left;display:inline;}
table{clear:both;}
div.TD,td{border:1px solid black;}
div.TD,td{background:#409152;}
div.TD,td{margin:15px;padding:5px}
div.TD > div,td > div{background:#1E4C6D;}
div.TD > div,td > div{width:90px;height:60px;}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="TR">
 <div class="TD">
  <div></div>
 </div>
 <div class="TD">
  <div></div>
 </div>
</div>

<table>
 <tr>
  <td><div></div></td>
  <td><div></div></td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because [that's what the spec dictates](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html#table-layout).

> ### 17.5 Visual layout of table contents
>
> Internal table elements generate rectangular [boxes](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#box-dimensions) with content and borders. Cells have padding as well. **Internal table elements do not have margins.**

<sub>(emphasis added)</sub>

Comment: they do, its just set in the table as "border-spacing".

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight `border-spacing` isn't `margin`, though. And the question really was not "how do I get around this", which is what your answer says, but "why does this particular property not work".

Comment: @AndrewBarber its kinda like a replacement.

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight still, that's not what the question asks.

Comment: @MattBall fine i still think its helpful and belongs here

Comment: @MattBall, thanks for that big clue.  What gets me is that I did run that code through CSS Lint, and not a peep from it about the margin directive for `td`...  Now that I know that such a directive is "officially" useless (if not downright invalid) I realize that that CSS Lint is not terribly useful...

Answer (score 0):

because it is set in the table use:

```
table{
    border-spacing: 5px; 
}
```

or the like.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you're out of luck. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14089050/2723382) on stack overflow links to some [W3 docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/tables.html) that rule out margins for "internal table elements".