# Add distances between 2 <div> of property display: table-cell

Tags: css

I have 2 `<div>` which have the styling property `display: table-cell`. I need to add left and right margin to the `<div>` and adding `margin: 0 10px` does not work. And I cannot add padding: 0 10px because the `<div>` background was set to a color and the `<div>` have border too. So if I add padding the `<div>` looks like it keep on expanding. I need to separate the 2 `<div>` by some pixels. Any ideas?

```
<body style="background: #555;">

<div style="width: 100px; background: #fff; margin: 0 10px; display: table-cell; border: 1px solid #000">
</div>

<div style="background: #fff; margin: 0 10px; display: table-cell; border: 1px solid #000">
</div>

</body>
```

Comment: Post a complete code example in your question please.

Comment: Similar question here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14227148/how-do-i-add-margin-between-divs-that-are-set-to-display-table-cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add another `<div>` between your 2 `<div>`. And add these styling rules to that `<div>`:

```
width:10px; // The distance you wish to separate the 2 divs'
display: table-cell;
background: transparent;
```

This is a simple hack technique. This inserts a transparent `<div>` between those two and looks like your `<div>`s are separated by margins.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a border.

```
<div class="tableCell"></div>
<div class="tableCell"></div>

.tableCell {
    background: green;
    border-left: 5px solid white;
    display: table-cell;
    height: 100px;
    width: 50px;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/eBF5j/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add distance between them. Just change the display property of both div's to inline-block and set the margin property.

```
div
{
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px;
}
```

Comment: Your welcome @CroResistor, you can mark this as the answer if it fixes your problem.

Comment: But I come across a new issue. The basic reason why I set `display: table-cell` was 1st `<div>` has fixed width say 100px. And the right one will automatically take the available width based on screen resolution. Now changing to inline block does not make the 2nd `<div>` to take the balance width of the window.

Comment: @CroResistor, just change the display: property of the second div to block.