# Gap between resources in Fullcalendar timegrid plugin

Tags: html, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-5

Using timegrid plugin, how to add gap between two resources.
I need gutter between the tables for Brandon and Justin

[image]

Comment: have you tried to do anything with CSS?

Comment: These are td elements. Margins wont work. I was thinking if we can insert a dummy resource at the middle. But dont know how I will prevent it from spanning to 7columns

Comment: What about using border separation? https://stackoverflow.com/a/14959544/5947043

Comment: Or one of these perhaps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/716442/css-cell-margin